# How to show FrameLabel and AxesLabel simultaneously with PlotTheme -> "Scientific"

Tags: plotting, labeling

I'm using mathematica 12.3. The function I need to plot is of order $10^4$, and I want to display a multiplier "$\times 10^4$" besides the $y$-axix while keeping FrameLabels $x,y$.

With following code

```
Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 3}, 
     PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
     FrameLabel -> {x, x^2}, 
     AxesLabel -> {, MaTeX@"\\times10^4"}]
```

I get

[image: this]

,  where the AxesLabel doesn't show the multiplier.

If I remove `PlotTheme`,

```
Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 3}, 
     FrameLabel -> {x, x^2}, 
     AxesLabel -> {, MaTeX@"\\times10^4"}]
```

I get

[image]

, where the FrameLabel doesn't show anymore.

How shall I make it through, as simply as possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Drawbacks of existing answers**

@cvgmt's answer is helpful, but actually in my case, my $y$-axis label is very long, and `Placed` command doesn't show at desired postion.

For example, with a very long label and position `{0.1,1}`, I get

[image]

, where the $\times 10^4$ is placed above the whole graph. If I set the position to be `{0.1,0.9}`, I get something like

[image]

As it turns out, the position is now relative to `Frame`, not the whole Graph.

I don't know what causes it, and it's no use to replace `Scaled` by `ImageScaled` or just `{0.1,0.9}`.

---

**My Improvement**

I found [`Overlay`] to place one graph above another. And following codes

```
Overlay[{
    Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 3}, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
        ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, 20}, {Automatic, 20}}, 
        FrameLabel -> {x, MaTeX@"\\text{A Very Very Very Very Very Long Label}"}],

    Graphics[Inset[MaTeX@"\\times10^4", 
        ImageScaled@{0.18, 0.93}],
        ImageSize -> Small]
}]
```

will give

[image]

, which performs well.

`ImagePadding` is needed, otherwise $\times10^4$ will be cut off at the frame border.

Answer (score 3):

Working around.

```
Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 3}, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
 FrameLabel -> {x, x^2}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[MaTeX@"\\times10^4", {Top, Left}]]
```

[image]

```
Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 3}, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
 FrameLabel -> {x, x^2}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[MaTeX@"\\times10^4", {0.1, 1}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

maybe like this

```
Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 3}, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
 FrameLabel -> (MaTeX[#, FontSize -> 20] &) /@ {"x", 
    "x^2 \\ \\times 10^4"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
<< MaTeX`

Plot[x^2
 , {x, 0, 3}
 , PlotTheme -> "Scientific"
 , FrameLabel -> {
   MaTeX@"x", RowBox[
     {Spacer[90]
      , MaTeX@"x^2"
      , Spacer[70]
      , Rotate[
       MaTeX@"\\times10^4", -π/2]}] // DisplayForm
   }
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`AxisObject`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AxisObject.html); an experimental function in 13.1.

I have made most features [`Transparent`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transparent.html) so only the [`AxisLabel`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AxisLabel.html) remains.  Also had to [`ImagePadding`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImagePadding.html) above the to make space for the label.

```
Plot[
 x^2, {x, 0, 3}
 , PlotTheme -> "Scientific"
 , FrameLabel -> {x, x^2}
 , ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, 20}}
 , Prolog -> {
   AxisObject[{"Vertical", -0.05}
    , AxisStyle -> Transparent
    , TicksStyle -> Transparent
    , LabelStyle -> Opacity[1]
    , AxisLabel -> 
       Placed[TraditionalForm["\[Times]\[MediumSpace]\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(10\), \(4\)]\)"]
       , Above
       ]
    ]
   }]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm using 12.3, so these codes don't seem to work in my PC, but thank you for the same. I'll try it after updating.